# Cannot Port Existing Visual Studio Qt Project To Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, visual-studio-2013

I developped a Qt 5.5 application using OpenCV and Flycapture camera libraries in Visual Studio 2013. Now, I would like to compile, build, and run this code in Ubuntu 14.04. I kept track of the steps in that [link](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/porting/qt/). After applying the step 11, I encountered this error [message](http://postimg.org/image/ildrey9ap/). Actually, I added the include path of Flycapture in Visual Studio. I don’ t know how to fix this problem.

Comment: FYI: posting error messages, source code and the like as links to external sources is generally frowned upon here; it's better if you just put it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile that library on Ubuntu then include it in your project.